# underscore to find min and max of object value

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

As per the tutorial [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/getting-cozy-with-underscore-js/),

> A collection can either be an array or an object, an associate array
>   in JavaScript

does that mean all the functions under `collection` is equally applicable to object literals.
For example, I wanted to pick the values based on a condition. Say,

```
var obj = {
"1": {id: 1, val: 2},
"2": {id: 2, val: 5},
"3": {id: 3, val: 8},
"4": {id: 4, val: 1}
}
```

I want to find max and min of val field. Looking at the API, I was thinking to use `pluck` to get an array of `val`, then do `min` and `max`.

- can I apply pluck to object (as the api example show the use in an array of objects)
- is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: Plain js Filter with Math. Perhaps ?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

> does that mean all the functions under collection is equally applicable to object literals?

[Yes](http://underscorejs.org/#collections).

> can I apply pluck to object (as the api example show the use in an array of objects)

Have you tried it? Yes, you can, but you will get back an array.

> is there a better way?

`Math.min.apply(null, _.pluck(obj, "val"))` (or `_.min(_.pluck(obj, "val"))`) for getting the minimum *value* is fine. Yet, if you wanted to get the whole object (with id) you might also use the [`iterator` parameter](http://underscorejs.org/#max) of min/max:

```
var lowest = _.min(obj, function(o){return o.val;});
```

Comment: Beautiful answer.  Thanks!

Comment: _.pluck is replaced for _.map in the latest Lodash version. Example will be like this: _.min(_.map(obj, "val"))

Comment: Great Answer i got this form `var min = (_.min(val, function(o){return o.displayorder;})).displayorder;`

Comment: What about an object with different keys that are created dynamically?

Comment: @tdelam Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Could you please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide an example input there?

Comment: @Bergi done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876679/taking-the-lowest-number-from-a-list-of-objects-that-have-dynamic-keys/53876755#53876755 and answered.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this, and great if you want to return multiple rows that all have a high value, is as such:

```
_.where(obj, {score: _.max(_.pluck(obj, 'value'))});
```

Answer (score -1):

No need to be fancy. Just create an array of the target values with the `map` function and use `_min` to find the minimum value.

**Standard**

```
var minimum = _.min(data.map(function(rec) {return rec.val}))
```

**ES6**

```
let minimum = _.min(data.map((rec) => {return rec.val}))
```

Comment: Can further simplify the ES6 (although IMO such alliterative syntax make the code less readable ) to the "implicit return", dropping the curly braces & return statement.   

let minimum = _.min(data.map((rec) => rec.val))