# Taking the lowest number from a list of objects that have dynamic keys

Tags: javascript

I am creating an object with dynamic keys as seen here:

```
const myObject = [
  {PINO: 1764},
  {FANH: 2737},
  {WQTR: 1268},
  {CICO: 1228}
];
```

I want to get the key and value with the lowest value, in this case it's `{CICO: 1228}`.

How I create this object is like so:

```
  let basic = [];

  _.map(values, value => {
    let result = value[Object.keys(value)].reduce((c, v) => {
      // sum up the amounts per key
      c[Object.keys(value)] = (c[Object.keys(value)] || 0) + parseInt(v.amount);
      return c;
    }, {});
    basic.push(result);
  }) 

  console.log(basic) => [{PINO: 1764}, {FANH: 2737}, {WQTR: 1268}, {CICO: 1228}]
```

How can I get the lowest number with it's key from the `basic` object? I tried using sort and taking the lowest number but the keys are created dynamically so I don't think I have anything I can sort against.

Comment: So small side question.  Why are you creating an array of single key objects, vs just one object with multiple keys?  Also, if there is an issue with the keys being dynamic, that's an easy thing to change.  Nothing says you couldn't change your object to `{ key: 'PINO', value: 1764 }`, no?

Comment: @Taplar yes, good point!

Comment: However, the value of that key is a sum of values that is an array of an object. The `PINO` has a total value of `1764` in this case so when that function reduces, it leaves an array with single object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate the array with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), get the values of the objects via [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), and take the one with the lower number:

```js
const myObject = [
  {PINO: 1764},
  {FANH: 2737},
  {WQTR: 1268},
  {CICO: 1228}
];

const result = myObject.reduce((r, o) => 
  Object.values(o)[0] < Object.values(r)[0] ? o : r
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I like your cat

Comment: He was a great cat :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty inconvenient way to store data since the keys are more-or-less useless and you need to look at the values of each object to do anything. But you can do it if you need to with something like:

```js
const myObject = [
    {PINO: 1764},
    {FANH: 2737},
    {WQTR: 1268},
    {CICO: 1228}
  ];

let least = myObject.reduce((least, current) => Object.values(least)[0] < Object.values(current)[0] ? least : current)
console.log(least)
```

If it was a large list, you might benefit from converting the array to a different format so you don't need to keep creating the `Object.values` array.

Comment: Thank you, the keys are actually codes that are used to map data, they're required

Comment: @tdelam You should be able to do better with a format like `[{key: "PINO", value: 1764}, {key:"FANH", …}, …]`.